# What is a django-like framework for PHP with auto-generated CRUD pages?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, crud

I'm looking for a simple MVC framework for PHP and would like something that handles basic user auth (for the admin) and generates it's own CRUD pages out of the box.

Edit: I'd really like something that creates these admin pages on the fly or "automatically" instead of the whole "baking" concept or having to manually update the CRUD pages via some generator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)?

Using [bake](http://book.cakephp.org/view/113/Code-Generation-with-Bake) you can generate Models, Views and Controllers with CRUD.
Cake also has a [Security component](http://book.cakephp.org/view/324/The-Security-Component) and [Access Control Lists (ACL)](http://book.cakephp.org/view/171/Access-Control-Lists).

Comment: @Matt You'll get the ability to up vote posts at 15 rep. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You can accept an answer regardless of reputation though ;)

Answer (score 7):

[Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) has a great admin generator based on ORM models.

Comment: I think this is a better suggestion than cakePHP and others although it takes more time to learn/master.

Comment: @Chris I understand it's been well over 10 years since you wrote this comment, but still, any chance you can elaborate on why, or maybe even reconsider your statement?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [QCodo](http://www.qcodo.com)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a few PHP frameworks and right now the one i find the easiest is [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

It doesn't generate CRUD on the fly but does the rest of what you want in a rather simple way. It also has lots of extensions for most of the common jobs.