# Any framework for PHP, as effective as Django for Python?

Tags: php, python, django, frameworks

I am using python with django. There I can simply make form from models and also it had builtin Admin.

I am eager to know corresponding framework for PHP with all this facilities.

I have encountered lot some similar questions like this, but they had not compared the frameworks with django.  Experts Please Suggest.

Comment: See [What is a django-like framework for PHP with auto-generated CRUD pages?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490670/what-is-a-django-like-framework-for-php-with-auto-generated-crud-pages).

Comment: Can you define 'effective'?  Do you mean 'full featured'?  'Efficient'?

Answer (score 3):

I'd try Symfony.

What you're referring to sounds like "scaffolding"

Comment: The Django admin serves as an interface for administration to be used by site staff, and is quite polished and complete - it's not quite like the bare bones CRUD generation found in other frameworks.

Comment: But maybe, out there is a plugin for symphony closer to django admin

Answer (score 2):

I've had good success with Zend in the past.  It has a lot of functionality in its libraries and it is all completely decoupled, so you can use whichever parts best fit your task, leaving out other things all together.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have built in admin, but I like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/). It really gives you freedom with your code without getting in the way.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Yii](http://yiiframework.com/). It's based on the Model-View-Controller pattern, like most of the other PHP frameworks mentioned here. It uses templates, can do scaffolding, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Another one that once saved my ass in a project with close deadline was [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)