# something similar to python-DJANGO in PHP?

Tags: php, django, frameworks

Does anybody know of something similar to django in PHP ?
I am looking for something that is a simple to use as django.

I have been using django for quite a long and now I have to do some development in PHP and I was expecting to use something similar

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any framework for PHP, as effective as Django for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030026/any-framework-for-php-as-effective-as-django-for-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a django-like framework for PHP with auto-generated CRUD pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490670/what-is-a-django-like-framework-for-php-with-auto-generated-crud-pages)

Comment: @Gordon thanks for those links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There are lots of MVC frameworks for PHP](http://www.phpwact.org/php/mvc_frameworks) - it's hard to say which of these are "similar to Django" because of the variance in featuresets (and most folks don't even really use all of what is available in Django).  But if you're just looking for a framework that uses the MVC paradigm, you now have  a handy list to look through as well as some Google-able phrases

Comment: Thanks I was expecting that maybe someone had already tried to find django's 'cousin' in PHP. I am mostly looking for something that has the same simple URL pattern configuration ORM and template system - if exists.

Answer (score 2):

Yii is very similiar to Django, try it

Answer (score 2):

[Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) is the most Django-like PHP framework up to date. It's been released just few months ago, so don't expect full documentation or LTS version, but it has several features that are very similar to Django: Twig (template engine), Bundles (almost like applications in Django), ORM and Assetic (library for handling static resources).